The buttons don't work on Apple smartphones, but they work fine on other devices
This Twig code with Symfony 6 works correctly on a PC, an Android smartphone or tablet and an Apple IOS tablet. However, the two buttons 'Close' and 'Confirm' are not clickable on an IOS smartphone.
{% if tabVarRoute is not defined %}
    {% set tabVarRoute = {'id': objId} %}
{%  endif %}

{% embed '@Tabler/embeds/modal.html.twig' with {id: modalName ~ objId} %}
    {% block modal_size 'modal-extra-sm' %}
    {% block modal_body %}
        <div class="text-center">
            {% if cfmMessage is defined %}
                <div class="mb-2 text-center"><i class="ti ti-help-hexagon icon text-primary icon-lg"></i></div>
                <h3>Demande de confirmation</h3><div class="text-muted">{{ cfmMessage }}</div>
            {% else %}
                <div class="mb-2 text-center"><i class="ti ti-skull icon text-danger icon-lg"></i></div>
                <h3>Danger !</h3><div class="text-muted">Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer définitivement l'enregistrement {{ objId }} ?</div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block modal_footer %}
        <div class="w-100">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <a href="#" class="btn w-100" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fermer</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {% set strToken = cfmMessage is defined ? 'confirm' : 'delete' %}
                    {% set strColor = cfmMessage is defined ? 'primary' : 'danger' %}
                    <form method="post" action="{{ path(strPath, tabVarRoute) }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token(strToken ~ objId) }}">
                        <button class="btn btn-{{ strColor }} w-100">Confirmer</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}

I've tried this on several models (XR, iphone 6, iphone 12) and several browsers (Safari, Chrome, Brave) and the behavior is always the same.
Normal operation is that both buttons can be clicked and the delete or cancel actions executed.
On an iPhone, the buttons are not clickable. Surprisingly, on an Apple tablet, the behavior is correct, as it is on an Android device or PC.
Here is the html :
<div  class="modal modal-blur fade " id="delete4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delete4_label">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-extra-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content ">
             <div  class="modal-header ">
                <h5 class="modal-title " id="delete4_label"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fermer"></button>                
            </div>
            <div  class="modal-body ">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="mb-2 text-center">
                        <i class="ti ti-skull icon text-danger icon-lg"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Danger !</h3>
                    <div class="text-muted">Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer définitivement l'enregistrement 4 ?</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div  class="modal-footer ">
                <div class="w-100">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <a href="#" class="btn w-100" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fermer</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <form method="post" action="/admin/user/4">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="8ca69f10.Z0qyGLRnaHuvIQZdlSXT9C3zZcCp5SWOJbxaEE3d_jo.EQL_e-MDGz6WR3QN_k-fmGCrKq_otXXUStk3VBS6pnIOLOFv9zMfQ-YTZQ">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger w-100">Confirmer</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>             


please post the (generated) HTML and not the template. This has nothing to do with twig as your problem is clientside
